# Windows application which has some processes in one window

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, browser, process

Chrome, IE, firefox has one parent process and some render processes. But these render processes' window(tab) are located in a main parent window.
How do their window(tab) attach on it?
Do they use windows API like ::SetParent ?

Comment: I'd assume that there is a main thread (GUI thread) which renders everything, and the other threads are like data sources which tell the main thread what to show to the user. When you switch between tabs, the main thread just switches to other data source thread, and if the thread dies unexpectedly it just stops displaying the tab.

At least thats how I'd begin my attempt to do something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When the other threads tell the main thread what to show, what kinds of data are sent to the main thread? I think html data is already parsed to DOM tree in the other thread, so render tree data is sent to the main thread.

Comment: I have no idea :D The way I'd try to do it is that when the user switches to a new tab the GUI sends a request to this tabs thread for data. When it receives data from the worker thread (for example it's a huge web page that takes a lot of time to load) it renders it. The threads may share a buffer of some kind and the worker thread fills it, so when GUI sees new data there during its render loop it copies it to its own DOM tree. Anyway I just realized that this may not be a good question according to SO rules - you should research and try some approaches by yourself and then ask for help.

Comment: I see. I'll try to research. Thank you, Losiowaty!